# Why is this an incorrect usage of a namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm learning c#, but I'm not quite sure about namespaces. I know I could leave off any "using" statements, and just say System.Console.WriteLine, or I could say "using System" and then say "Console.WriteLine", but I do not understand why the following doesn't work.

```
using System.Console;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This feature is new to C# 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console` is not a namespace, but a class. `WriteLine` is a static method of that class (so you don't need an instance to use it). In fact, the `Console` class itself appears to be static (so there are no instances).

You cannot `using` a class in C# 5.0 and earlier. According to this MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) You *can* do this with static classes only in C# 6.0 (the code you wrote would compile and work).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `Console` class.

Comment: you cannot `using` a class (in C# 5). In C# 6.0 this IS possible.

Comment: @HighCore, Thanks for the heads up! I haven't used C# 6.0 yet, so perhaps you could write an answer for C# 6?

Comment: So it would be correct to say that Console is a class that belongs to the System namespace, which is why the above code is incorrect?

Comment: @david that is correct. As HighCore pointed out, your code is perfectly fine in C# 6 though.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the `using` statement only includes namespaces. Since `Console` is not a namespace, you can't use it like that.

This is one of the features that will be included in C# 6, see the [relevant Roslyn page](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home):

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
| Feature              | Example                          |  C#  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Using static members | using System.Console; … Write(4) | Done |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```